# Intelij Creating new package with new name

Tags: java

So this is simple but I cant find a solution.

Inside `src/main/java` I have package `com.practice` when I try to create new package with name `com.practice.spring` Intelij just rename my old package `com.practice` to `com.practice.spring`. Any solution, this is so frustrating. Also, I want new package inside `src/main/java` no inside `src/main/java/com.practice`

Answer (score 1):

Packages are essentially a folder structure. So when you create a package com.practice.spring, it creates 3 folders underneath, com -> practice -> spring. Package views in intellij (and eclipse) will combine empty folders. So if you create a class (even a package-info.java will do) in com.practice, you will see them as separate packages.

[image]